# MSP430 compiler not found when using Contiki-NG

Tags: iot, msp430, contiki, cooja, contiki-ng

I'm trying to simulate a Sky mote with the Cooja simulator shipped with the Contiki-NG project. I access the simulator as stated at their wiki:

```
cd contiki-ng/tools/cooja
ant
```

But when I try to compile the hello-world example, which seems to execute the command

```
make hello-world.sky TARGET=sky
```

Cooja returns the following error message:

```
> make hello-world.sky TARGET=sky 
make: msp430-gcc: File or directory does not exists
make: msp430-gcc: File or directory does not exists
/bin/sh: 1: msp430-gcc: not found
/bin/sh: 1: msp430-gcc: not found
/bin/sh: 1: test: -lt: unexpected operator
  CC        ../../os/contiki-main.c
make: msp430-gcc: File or directory does not exists
make: *** [../../Makefile.include:366: build/sky/obj/contiki-main.o] Error 127
Process returned error code 2
```

I checked that the msp430-gcc was installed and that the file ../../os/contiki-main.c was ok. So why am I facing this error?

Comment: Can I ask how did you check for `msp430-gcc`? Are you sure you can run it from the same shell you start Cooja in (it must be in the PATH and for the right architecture).

Comment: Anyway, we recommend to use the Docker image: https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Docker so you don't have to worry about installing the compilers yourself.